# Building Android NDK in Eclipse in Ubuntu

Tags: android, android-ndk

I'm new in Ubuntu 13.04 and I'm trying to build ndk in my app. I'm using below command in terminal.

```
cd workspace/my_app   <---- my app location
ndk-build
```

But it says "ndk-build: command not found"
I searched this problem and I saw that there is something like path issue.
My android-ndk-r9 is located at my downloads folder
Can anyone give some thoughts how to make this? Because I don't really have idea how to fix this in Ubuntu.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. figure out the location of your ndk-build binary
2. add the path to your PATH environment variable by executing this command in the shell:

   `export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/your/ndk-build-binary`

   for example if it is in your downloads folder as you've written it would look something like this (be sure to take care of lower-case and upper-case as linux is case sensitive with file and directory names - so it might be `Downloads` instead of `downloads` in your case):

   `export PATH=$PATH:~/downloads/android-ndk-r9/`

then it is possible for you to execute ndk-build from your `workspace/my_app` directory

Comment: Hey sir the terminal says:   Android NDK: WARNING: APP_PLATFORM android-14 is larger than android:minSdkVersion 7 in ./AndroidManifest.xml    
Install        : libg726_jni.so => libs/armeabi/libg726_jni.so
Install        : libspeex_jni.so => libs/armeabi/libspeex_jni.so

Comment: and how should I know if I already compile ndk to my project?

Comment: Hi, I would recommend to raise a new question for this - because it's a different problem and people who might be able to help will not look at these comments but rather at a dedicated question with appropriate header. cheers!

Answer (score 0):

try to call the command ndk-build using the path of the location of ndk

path of your ndk/ndk-build

Comment: this is the path of my ndk : --  /downloads/android-ndk-r9/    How can I command this?

Comment: and how should I know if I already compile ndk to my project?